# limiting a cell to two numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

```
=IF(SUM(B12-B10)<0,0,SUM(B12-B10))
=IF(SUM(B12-B10)>3270,3270,SUM(B12-B10))
```

I am trying to write an excel formula that will not allow the cell's value to go below 0 or above 3270. I have the two formulas above but I am not sure how to get them both into once cell.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Try `=MIN(MAX(SUM(B12, -B10), 0), 3270)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the second IF statement in the False of the First IF statement.

```
=IF(SUM(B12-B10)<0,0,IF(SUM(B12-B10)>3270,3270,SUM(B12-B10)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the *SUM()* function:

```
=IF(B12-B10<0,0,IF(B12-B10>3270,3270,B12-B10))
```

Comment: I had originally thought the same regarding the [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) but using it like `SUM(B12, -B10)` would guard against the #VALUE! error if the subtraction involved alphabetic characters so it may be be needed, just not used correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
=IF(SUM(B12-B10)<0,0,IF(SUM(B12-B10)>3270,3270,SUM(B12-B10)))
```

Cheers